# Webscraping R: no applicable method for 'read_xml' applied to an object of class "list"

Tags: html, r, xml, web-scraping

I have this website over here: https://www.realtor.ca/map#ZoomLevel=4&Center=58.695434%2C-96.000000&LatitudeMax=72.60462&LongitudeMax=-26.39063&LatitudeMin=35.66836&LongitudeMin=-165.60938&Sort=6-D&PropertyTypeGroupID=1&PropertySearchTypeId=1&TransactionTypeId=2&Currency=CAD

Within the `<div class = "cardcon">` section, I am trying to extract the hyperlink for each individual house on this page:

[image]

For example, manually inspecting the `<div class = "cardcon">` section, I found the following links I needed:

```
# desired results
- https://www.realtor.ca/real-estate/25050003/lot-1-norcross-rd-duncan-west-duncan
- https://www.realtor.ca/real-estate/25050002/39-legacy-lane-hamilton-ancaster
- https://www.realtor.ca/real-estate/25049996/53-16-fourth-st-orangeville-orangeville
- etc.
```

I noticed that all these desired links are contained within the following type of HTML structure: `<a href="*****INSERT LINK HERE****" data-binding="href=DetailsURL" class="blockLink listingDetailsLink" target="_blank">`

I had the following question: Using the R programming language, would it be possible to save every link on this page which is contained within this `<a href = .... target="_blank">`  structure?

For example - I tried this code here:

```
library(rvest)
library(httr)
library(XML)

url<-"https://www.realtor.ca/map#ZoomLevel=4&Center=58.695434%2C-96.000000&LatitudeMax=72.60462&LongitudeMax=-26.39063&LatitudeMin=35.66836&LongitudeMin=-165.60938&Sort=6-D&PropertyTypeGroupID=1&PropertySearchTypeId=1&TransactionTypeId=2&Currency=CAD"

# making http request
resource <- GET(url)

# converting all the data to HTML format
parse <- htmlParse(resource)

# scrapping all the href tags
links <- xpathSApply(parse, path="//a", xmlGetAttr, "href")

page <-read_html(links)

Error in UseMethod("read_xml") : 
  no applicable method for 'read_xml' applied to an object of class "list"
```

But I am not sure how to complete this.

Can someone please show me what to do next?

Thank you!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Even though the link is URL-encoded, it is better to call on their API. Check out the network section - you will find this:

[image: API picture]

The parameters that is encoded in your URL can be found in the `payload` tab. With `httr2` you can retrieve the same information as the site.

library(tidyverse)
library(httr2)

```
content <- "https://api2.realtor.ca/Listing.svc/PropertySearch_Post" %>%
  request() %>%
  req_user_agent("Mozilla/5.0 (Windows NT 10.0; Win64; x64) AppleWebKit/537.36 (KHTML, like Gecko) Chrome/74.0.3729.169 Safari/537.36") %>% 
  req_body_form(
    ZoomLevel = 4,
    LatitudeMax = '67.16743',
    LongitudeMax = '-56.40166',
    LatitudeMin = '-5.70993',
    LongitudeMin = '-139.10674',
    CurrentPage = 2,
    Sort = '6-D',
    PropertyTypeGroupID = 1,
    ropertySearchTypeId = 1,
    TransactionTypeId = 2,
    Currency = 'CAD',
    RecordsPerPage = 36,
    ApplicationId = 1,
    CultureId = 1,
    Version = '7.0'
  ) %>%
  req_headers('referer' = 'https://www.realtor.ca/') %>%
  req_perform() %>%
  resp_body_json(simplifyVector = TRUE)

content %>% 
  getElement('Results') %>%  
  as_tibble

# A tibble: 12 x 21
   Id       MlsNum~1 Publi~2 Build~3 Indiv~4 Prope~5 Busin~6 Land$~7 Posta~8 Relat~9 Statu~*
   <chr>    <chr>    <chr>   <chr>   <list>  <chr>   <df[,0> <chr>   <chr>   <chr>   <chr>  
 1 25049990 W5821020 "Rare ~ 3       <df>    $1,275~         30.2 x~ L9E1J1  /real-~ 1      
 2 25049994 W5821034 "The B~ 3       <df>    $1,499~         29.5 x~ L6M2Z8  /real-~ 1      
 3 25049980 N5821033 "Immac~ 3       <df>    $999,0~         20.01 ~ L4S2K9  /real-~ 1      
 4 25049978 N5821026 "Ravin~ 3       <df>    $990,0~         24.64 ~ L6B0G6  /real-~ 1      
 5 25049977 N5821022 "A Rea~ 2       <df>    $599,9~         NA      L3T4S3  /real-~ 1      
 6 25049976 N5821019 "**** ~ 4       <df>    $1,468~         40.03 ~ L3X2H9  /real-~ 1      
 7 25049973 E5821030 "7 Yea~ 4       <df>    $1,799~         151.71~ L0B1A0  /real-~ 1      
 8 25049971 E5821014 "This ~ 3       <df>    $849,0~         27.1 x~ M4J4C3  /real-~ 1      
 9 25049966 C5821039 "Brigh~ 1       <df>    $568,8~         NA      M2N0L2  /real-~ 1      
10 25049967 C5821042 "Come ~ 1       <df>    $599,0~         NA      M5V0G8  /real-~ 1      
11 25049965 C5821029 "Wow! ~ 1       <df>    $514,9~         NA      M3C1S5  /real-~ 1      
12 25049963 C5821025 "High ~ 2       <df>    $1,199~         NA      M5C0A6  /real-~ 1      
# ... with 26 more variables: Building$Bedrooms <chr>, $StoriesTotal <chr>, $Type <chr>,
#   $Ammenities <chr>, Property$Type <chr>, $Address <df[,5]>, $Photo <list>,
#   $Parking <list>, $ParkingSpaceTotal <chr>, $TypeId <chr>, $OwnershipType <chr>,
#   $ConvertedPrice <chr>, $OwnershipTypeGroupIds <list>, $ParkingType <chr>,
#   $PriceUnformattedValue <chr>, $AmmenitiesNearBy <chr>, PhotoChangeDateUTC <chr>,
#   HasNewImageUpdate <lgl>, Distance <chr>, RelativeURLEn <chr>, RelativeURLFr <chr>,
#   Media <list>, InsertedDateUTC <chr>, TimeOnRealtor <chr>, Tags <list>, ...
# i Use `colnames()` to see all variable names
```

Comment: 1) I tried to visit the link to the API that you used (https://api2.realtor.ca/Listing.svc/PropertySearch_Post) - but it tells me that "Access Denied" and that I need to confirm I am not a robot ... but there is no captcha that allows me to do so. However, even though I can not access this API website, your code still runs on my computer. I wonder why this is?

Comment: 2) Are you also seeing 12 listings per page? The website tells me that there are roughly 175,000 listings - meaning that there are roughly 14,500 pages. In theory, I could just loop your code 14,500 times?

Comment: 3) While your way seems to be far more efficient and better  - I was trying to approach this problem in two steps : first, find the link for every home being listed - then, scrape the price information from these links ... without using the API. Would it have been possible to do this?

Comment: 1) I am not an expert but these APIs checks how you are accessing the data. The code simply emulates a valid request, while simply visiting the URL is prohibited. You will need to feed it correct info to retrieve the data - such with `req_body_form`.

Comment: 2) You can change the `RecordsPerPage` to a higher number such as 24. And perhaps you can loop through the parameter `CurrentPage`

Comment: 3) Links of the listings is also gathered from the API. Check the structure of the data. Should be a column called `RelativeDetailsURL`. Prices is also already in the dataset.

Comment: My original thoughts: perhaps the problem might be from interacting with the API? Is it possible to scrape the website directly (as I had started in my original question)?