# Webscraping Links on a Page

Tags: html, r, xml, web-scraping

I have this website over here: https://www.realtor.ca/map#ZoomLevel=4&Center=58.695434%2C-96.000000&LatitudeMax=72.60462&LongitudeMax=-26.39063&LatitudeMin=35.66836&LongitudeMin=-165.60938&Sort=6-D&PropertyTypeGroupID=1&PropertySearchTypeId=1&TransactionTypeId=2&Currency=CAD

Using R, within the `<div class = "cardcon">` section, I am trying to extract the hyperlink for each individual house on this page:

[image]

As an example, the desired output would be:

- https://www.realtor.ca/real-estate/25054113/4918-lafontaine-hanmer
- https://www.realtor.ca/real-estate/25054111/77-shady-shores-drive-w-winnipeg-waterside-estates
- etc.

In a previous question([Webscraping R: no applicable method for 'read_xml' applied to an object of class "list"](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/74371191/webscraping-r-no-applicable-method-for-read-xml-applied-to-an-object-of-class)), I learned how to use the API for this website, but this was producing problems.

Instead, I would like to try and learn how to extract the links (e.g. webscraping) **directly from this website without using the API.**

As an example, I tried to do this without the following code:

```
library(rvest)
library(httr)
library(XML)

url<-"https://www.realtor.ca/map#ZoomLevel=4&Center=58.695434%2C-96.000000&LatitudeMax=72.60462&LongitudeMax=-26.39063&LatitudeMin=35.66836&LongitudeMin=-165.60938&Sort=6-D&PropertyTypeGroupID=1&PropertySearchTypeId=1&TransactionTypeId=2&Currency=CAD"

# making http request
resource <- GET(url)

# converting all the data to HTML format
parse <- htmlParse(resource)

# scrapping all the href tags
links <- xpathSApply(parse, path="//a", xmlGetAttr, "href")

page <-read_html(links)

Error in UseMethod("read_xml") : 
  no applicable method for 'read_xml' applied to an object of class "list"
```

But I am not sure how to proceed with this - can someone please help me out?

Thank you!

Comment: The page you are requesting does not contain the information you are looking for. When your browser loads the page, it runs the scripts on that page, and one of these scripts is a call to the API. But when you download the page in R, the javascript is _not_ run, so the XHR call is not made and the extra information is not inserted into your HTML, giving different HTML from what you see in the browser pane. The API is the _only_ source of the information you want. You can either get this through direct http calls or by using browser automation e.g. RSelenium. There are no other options.

Answer (score 1):

I have been able to do it with the following code :

```
library(RSelenium)
library(rvest)
url <- "https://www.realtor.ca/map#ZoomLevel=4&Center=58.695434%2C-96.000000&LatitudeMax=71.71626&LongitudeMax=-54.64746&LatitudeMin=37.98958&LongitudeMin=-137.35254&Sort=6-D&PropertyTypeGroupID=1&PropertySearchTypeId=1&TransactionTypeId=2&Currency=CAD"
shell('docker run -d -p 4446:4444 selenium/standalone-firefox')
remDr <- remoteDriver(remoteServerAddr = "localhost", port = 4446L, browserName = "firefox")
remDr$open()
remDr$navigate(url)

web_Obj <- remDr$findElements("xpath", '//*[@id="ctl00"]/div/a')
web_Links <- lapply(X = web_Obj, FUN = function(x) x$getElementAttribute("href"))
web_Links <- unlist(web_Links)

web_Links
 [1] "https://www.realtor.ca/real-estate/25423501/47-whitehaven-road-ne-calgary-whitehorn"                                                   
 [2] "https://www.realtor.ca/real-estate/25423499/304-370-dieppe-drive-sw-calgary-currie-barracks"                                           
 [3] "https://www.realtor.ca/real-estate/25423497/539-rue-hudon-laval-fabreville-east"                                                       
 [4] "https://www.realtor.ca/real-estate/25423494/1850-rue-du-domaine-bastien-sainte-ad%C3%A8le-sainte-ad%C3%A8le"                           
 [5] "https://www.realtor.ca/real-estate/25423493/109-rue-laroche-salaberry-de-valleyfield-salaberry-de-valleyfield"                         
 [6] "https://www.realtor.ca/real-estate/25423492/496-rue-st-denis-saint-alexandre"                                                          
 [7] "https://www.realtor.ca/real-estate/25423489/2300-rue-des-h%C3%A9misph%C3%A8res-montr%C3%A9al-saint-laurent-new-saint-laurentbois-franc"
 [8] "https://www.realtor.ca/real-estate/25423488/709-rue-de-la-futaie-boucherville-le-bois%C3%A9"                                           
 [9] "https://www.realtor.ca/real-estate/25423487/10757-av-de-london-montr%C3%A9al-montr%C3%A9al-nord"                                       
[10] "https://www.realtor.ca/real-estate/25423486/1018-rue-des-carougeois-qu%C3%A9bec-sainte-foysillerycap-rouge-cap-rouge"                  
[11] "https://www.realtor.ca/real-estate/25423485/12-rue-beaudet-montr%C3%A9al-l%C3%AEle-bizardsainte-genevi%C3%A8ve-l%C3%AEle-bizard"       
[12] "https://www.realtor.ca/real-estate/25423484/2020-boul-ren%C3%A9-l%C3%A9vesque-o-111-montr%C3%A9al-ville-marie-central-west"
```